# Output this array php

Tags: php, arrays, output

Can someone help me output this array. not sure how to get the answer array output?

Here is the array outputed:

[image]

And this is what I have so far:

```
foreach($questions as $question) {
    echo $question['question'];

    foreach($question['answer'] as $answer) {
            'HOW DO I GET THE ANSWERS WHICH IS IN ARRAY'
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `$question['answer']` for `$question['answers']` (notice the plural form of *answer*) in your inner `foreach` loop as per your array.

Comment: I didnt notice that thank you... another thing... so it outputs but for some reason the "Answer is here" shows 5 times any ideas?

Comment: @levilucas Does your array contain it 5 times?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($question as $question) {
echo $question['question'];

foreach($question['answers'] as $answer) {
        echo $answer;
}
```

checkout the variable names ($question , $questions , $question['answers'] ,$question['answer'])